# Best way to calculate number of facets in geom_hline/_vline

Tags: r, ggplot2

When I combine `geom_vline()` with `facet_grid()` like so:

```
DATA <- data.frame(x = 1:6,y = 1:6, f = rep(letters[1:2],3))
ggplot(DATA,aes(x = x,y = y)) +
    geom_point() +
    facet_grid(f~.) +
    geom_vline(xintercept = 2:3,
               colour =c("goldenrod3","dodgerblue3"))
```

I get an error message stating `Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (4): colour` because there are two lines in each facet and there are two facets.  One way to get around this is to use `rep(c("goldenrod3","dodgerblue3"),2)`, but this requires that every time I change the faceting variables, I also have to calculate the number of facets and replace the magic number (`2`) in the call to `rep()`, which makes re-using ggplot code so much less nimble.

Is there a way to get the number of facets directly from ggplot for use in this situation?

Answer (score 2):

You could put the `xintercept` and `colour` info into a data.frame to pass to `geom_vline` and then use `scale_color_identity`.

```
ggplot(DATA, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
    geom_point() +
    facet_grid(f~.) +
    geom_vline(data = data.frame(xintercept = 2:3, 
                                 colour = c("goldenrod3","dodgerblue3") ), 
               aes(xintercept = xintercept, color = colour) ) +
    scale_color_identity()
```

This side-steps the issue of figuring out the number of facets, although that could be done by pulling out the number of unique values in the faceting variable with something like `length(unique(DATA$f))`.

Comment: Cool.  I didn't know about `scale_color_identity()`. I'll probably go with that.  The downside of `length(unique(DATA$f))` is that you have to take the same subset there as you do here: `ggplot(DATA[ some & subset | other], aes(...))`, and is a pain when you facet on two variables...

Comment: Unfortunately, using `scale_color_identity()` prevents me from using `aes(colour=foo)` with other graphical elements, such as points, when the field being mapped to the point color isn't a valid R color...